# Can't get ImageMagick run with php

Tags: php

I'm very frustrated with getting ImageMagick to run.

The Situation:
ImageMagick is installed on the Server. (My hosting provider did this. as a standard)
I asked my provider and they only said: the path to ImageMagick is /usr/bin/php_safemode and that i should "deposit" the path in my application. Whatever that means.

nothing works:

```
exec('convert SOME CODE') ;
```

doesn't work.

```
$im = new Imagick($image);
```

(these are no complete scripts, because not the scripts are the problem.. ) i have no idea how to test it. i mean ..no idea how to get it run. how to include this path in my script..

note: i have no access to php.ini or something like this.. my hosting provider told me that i can do it just include this path.. but how could this work?

Any ideas? tips?

i'm searching for an answer the whole day

Comment: Did you try `exec('/usr/bin/php_safemode/convert SOME CODE');`...?

Comment: THANK YOU! i knew that it's that simple. THX A LOT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
exec('/usr/bin/php_safemode/convert SOME CODE');
```

Comment: ya thx guys. this works. BUT how can i use this class.. Imagick?

Comment: wasn't me. maybe because you copy pasted DaveRandoms post?

Comment: I didn't copy/past Daves post! Honestly, he was just posting the same moment...Anyway, back to your topic: You should check your "info.php" if ImageMagick is loaded. With exec() you execute a command on the server, leaving php - which might be potentially dangerous: e.g. NEVER try this: exec("rm .")!

Comment: i'm sorry. i believe you. ;) THX AGAIN